# Jquery - - How do i simplify code

Tags: jquery, html

Currently am fetcing values user entred in the textbox,dropdown using the below code.

```
var test = new Object();
test.attribute = $("#Attribute_0").val();
test.operand = $("#Operand_0").val();
test.value = $("#Value_0").val();

var test = new Object();
test.attribute = $("#Attribute_1").val();
test.operand = $("#Operand_1").val();
test.value = $("#Value_1").val();
```

But as the list grows i thought there will be some other better way to do this so i came here.

my HTML code will be like below

```
<div>
    <input id="Attribute_0" name="Attribute_1" type="text">
    <select id="Operand_0">
    <input id="Value_0" type="text">
</div>

<div>
    <input id="Attribute_1" name="Attribute_1" type="text">
    <select id="Operand_1">
    <input id="Value_1" type="text">
</div>
```

Can i simplify my code with some foreach or any other better way ?

Please suggest

## Update

Ya my code is repeating.

Suppose if i have 10 list attributes like this there is no point doing that manually gettin values for each DIV .

How can i easily do this w/o rewritting code ?

Comment: your code is overwriting itself, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You know what the `class=""` attribute is, right?

Comment: Maybe a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ya i know itz repeating. how can i simplify this ?Updated my question

Comment: Thanks for the answers. All are helpful Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` method.

```
var data = $('div.classname').map(function() {
    var $elems = $(this).children();
    return {
        attribute: $elems.eq(0).val(),
        operand: $elems.eq(1).val(),
        value: $elems.eq(2).val()
    }
}).get();
```

Now `data` variable is an array of objects, you can also add classes to your form elements and selects them by their classNames instead of using `.eq` method.

Answer (score 3):

To be effecient, it'd be better having a class on each of your containing `<div>`'s and doing the `$.each` on this class, but with your current code you can do:

```
$.each($('div'), function(i, v) {
  var test = new Object();
  test.attribute = $("#Attribute_" + i).val();
  test.operand = $("#Operand_" + i).val();
  test.value = $("#Value_" + i).val();
});
```

Comment: Personal preference perhaps, but I think `$("div").each(` looks a bit cleaner than passing the collection to `$.each`.

Comment: Yep, either or, depending on preference :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to change your html, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <input class="Attribute" name="Attribute_0" type="text">
    <select class="Operand">
    <input class="Value" type="text">
</div>

<div class="item">
    <input class="Attribute" name="Attribute_1" type="text">
    <select class="Operand">
    <input class="Value" type="text">
</div>
```

Which would allow you to do this:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    var $item = $(this);

    var test = new Object();
    test.attribute = $item.find(".Attribute").val();
    test.operand = $item.find(".Operand").val();
    test.value = $item.find(".Value").val();

    // do stuff with test
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can organize foreach cycle for tag names. Something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<maxvalue; i++){
var test = new Object();
test.attribute = $("#Attribute_" + i).val();
test.operand = $("#Operand_"+ i).val();
test.value = $("#Value_"+ i).val();
}
```